# Understanding a statement: There exists a unique vector $w_0 ∈ W$ such that $ψ (w) = (w, w_0)$ for all $w ∈ W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

let $W$ be an inner product space, $\dim W = n$, and let $ψ: W → \mathbb{R}$ be linear.

Then there exists a unique vector $w_0 ∈ W$ such that $ψ (w) = (w, w_0)$ for all $w ∈ W$,

While $w_0 = \sum_{i=0}^n ψ (u_i)u_i$, where {$u_1, . . . , u_n$} is an orthonormal basis for $W$.

---

Here is my way of proof (I wrote $T$ as $\psi$ for readability):

Let $w \in W$.

$(w,w_0)=(w,T(u_1)u_1+...+T(u_n)u_n)=(w,T(u_1)u_1)+...+(w,T(u_n)u_n)=$

$T(u_j) \in \mathbb{R}$ so:

$=(w,u_1)T(u_1)+...+(w,u_n)T(u_n)=T((w,u_1)u_1+...+(w,u_n)u_n)=T(w)$

I will appreciate if someone can make this statment more clear for me to understand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can type `\in` and `\psi` instead of copying Unicode symbols

Comment: $(w,w_0)$? Do your brackets denote inner product? We normally write $\langle w,w_0\rangle$, using `\langle` and `\rangle`

Comment: Both $\psi(w)$ and $\left(w, \sum_{i=0}^m \psi(u_i)u_i\right)$ are linear maps of $w$. If you can show they agree on some convenient basis (hint, hint), then you've shown that they're equal everywhere. Also note that this expression only works when you have a **real** inner product space.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you, can you please look at my proof I just added? :)

Comment: Yeah, that works too; you can use the identity $w = (w, u_1)u_1 + \ldots + (w, u_n)u_n$ to obtain the result. I'm not really certain what you're asking for specifically. Did you want us to critique this proof? If so, I would suggest adding the [tag:solution-verification] tag.

Comment: For context, this is known as the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I would like to know, when should I use this statement? When asking me about finding a specific vector that does something to the whole basis?

Comment: @CalculusLover A version of this statement holds for Hilbert spaces, and it has uses there.